# Why do these restify functions end with "return next()"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, restify

I am looking at the documentation of restify.

http://restify.com/

I noticed that several functions need to end with `return next()`. Here are some examples;

```
function send(req, res, next) {
   res.send('hello ' + req.params.name);
   return next();
 }

 server.post('/hello', function create(req, res, next) {
   res.send(201, Math.random().toString(36).substr(3, 8));
   return next();
 });
 server.put('/hello', send);
 server.get('/hello/:name', send);
 server.head('/hello/:name', send);
 server.del('hello/:name', function rm(req, res, next) {
   res.send(204);
   return next();
 });
```

What is the purpose of `return next();`? Why do the functions need to end with it?

Comment: Open the page you've referred to and `ctrl+f` by the `next`. They have explanation right on their main page.

Comment: it's how basic callback chaining works, a one-shot event handler for the job being "done". in this case, it's being passed in, which is probably populated with the response, so in the put, it sends the result back to the other "res"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Restify's website](http://restify.com/):

> Note the use of next(). You are responsible for calling next() in order to run the next handler in the chain. As below, you can pass an Error object in to have restify automatically return responses to the client.

So basically if your function is the last handler in the chain you wouldn't need to call `next()` since there's no way of knowing this you add it and let Restify deal with it.

Comment: I see. So, this is why so many functions end with next() even if they don't need it. It is in case the programmer forgets to put it there later when it is needed. Is my understanding correct?